# .HTACCESS re-direct issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem in that after I remove the .php extension from my URL using a .htaccess re-write rule, I can no longer travel to directories 1 level down.

for example. if I navigate to `www.gameandshame.com/register.php` it will re-direct to `www.gameandshame.com/register` however, when I use a link to logout

`www.gameandshame.com/auth/login.php` it re-writes to `www.gameandshame.com/auth/login` however it produces a 404 error, the login and logout files are located inside the auth folder and it's pretty important I keep my website files ordered properly so I don't want to pull them to my main directory.

Does anybody know why they might be producing a 404 error?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gameandshame.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gameandshame.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.gameandshame.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.gameandshame.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]


#Handle Profile Re-directs
RewriteRule ^profile/?$ profile.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

#Handle Post re-directs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/?$ post.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/?$ post.php?postid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have these rules in root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gameandshame\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.gameandshame.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#Handle Post re-directs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/(.+)/?$ post.php?postid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: For some reason my form data will no longer post to /auth/login @anubhava

Comment: nevermind, I fixed the issue, I needed to POST the data to /auth/login and not login.php, thanks a ton!